# Tabs Closed Every Time I Close Laptop Screen

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, shutdown, browser-tabs

This isn’t a huge problem but it is very annoying. Every time I turn off my windows 7 laptop, all the tabs close and reopen. Including chrome, Firefox, etc. 
Mind you, this is not a shutting down case, I’m simply closing my laptop screen. I don’t remember changing any settings for this to happen, and it never used to happen. 
I’m appreciative of any replies I can get! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7, use the following:

Start, Control Panel, Hardware and Sound, Power Options, System Settings
You will be presented with a series of buttons to select how your laptop reacts to the power button being pressed, or the cover being closed.

[image: laptop buttons]